# Included PHP page doesn't execute code

Tags: php, apache, php-include

I have some code that's working on my server and when I put it up to a different server (both CentOS, Apache), the includeed file doesn't execute the code. So I get the following:

Main file

```
<div>
    <?php
    //This does include it, but as though it were text
    include( "/var/www/mypath/file.php" );
    ?>
</div>
```

File.php has the following code:

```
<div><? php echo $someString; ?></div>
```

Then the main file loads like this:

```
<div>
    <div><? php echo $someString; ?></div>
</div>
```

Why wouldn't the included file's code load?

Comment: Note that with `short_open_tags` on you can do : `<?=$someString?>` instead of the usual echo stuff.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably have `short_open_tags` off, so

```
<div><? php echo $someString; ?></div>
     ^^^^^^
```

with the space isn't recognized as an open tag. `<?php` would be, but you've got `<?[space]php`.